# Java image zoom

Tags: java, image, image-processing, zooming

I need help in my code.

```
int width = img.getXDim();
int height = img.getYDim();
int n = 3;

Image newImg = new ByteImage(width * n, height * n, 1);

        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){

    int p = img.getXYByte(x, y);

    newImg.setXYByte(n * x, n * y, p);
    newImg.setXYByte(n * x + 2, n * y, p);
    newImg.setXYByte(n * x, n * y + 2, p);
    newImg.setXYByte(n * x + 2, n * y + 2, p) ;  `
```

My problem is, I want to change n value (as 2, 9 or 0.5) so I can zoom in or zoom out my image.  But when I write `float n` for decimal numbers,  `setXYByte` says that I can use only `int,int,int` values.  With this code, I can only make my image 3 or more times bigger.  Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: *"Sorry for my bad English."*  I'll overlook bad English, but not laziness.  To make it easier for the reader, please use an upper case letter: 1) For the first letter in every sentence 2) For the word 'I' 3) For proper names like English (or class names etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You can "cast" floating point values to ints like this:

```
newImg.setXYByte((int) (n * x), (int) (n * y), p);
```

Casting discards the fractional part of the number so that something like 21.7 becomes 21.